# How to open media frame of wordpress in frontend?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in Wordpress and I want to add the media frame in front end which opens in back-end of Wordpress to my Wordpress application.

To open it in backend I am using `wp.media()` function; but it is not working in Front end.

Answer (score 1):

I have got my answer and I am posting the solution so that if someone else need to use it he/she can use it.

```
function add_media_upload_scripts() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
         return;
       }
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_media_upload_scripts');
```

Place this code in your Functions.php file.